# Is there any way to increase the number of candy made?

Tags: candy-box-2

In Candy Box 2, the candies are being produced at a rate of 1 candy per second. Is there any way to increase the potential amount of candy made at a faster rate? (notice that I am only up to the part where the person with the cellar in their house gives me a map.

Comment: Is this question a bad question?

Comment: I don't see a problem with it, I upvoted it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

During the game you will be able to access a Lollipop Farm (it's early on). Not only are you able to plant lollipops, but you can build a mill for 10,000 lollipops. Then you can feed the mill with more lollipops. This will increase your candy production.

Answer (score 3):

If you play some time, you'll get to the developer which gives you 6.000.000 candies everytime you kill him. If you wear the merchant's hat, you'll get 42.000.000 candies.
(Fast way to kill developer many times: Find purple shark fin in the sea and use BLACK HOLE spell and use TELEPORT SPELL directly after that. He'll hit himself with the black hole he creates if you use BLACK HOLE, ERASE MAGIC or BLACK DEMONS spell).

Answer (score 2):

Once you get the pink enchanted gloves, you can basically run the desert over and over to gain an extra about 40-60 candies each time. It has the added bonus of regenerating health faster than when you aren't in quests. So if you run low on health you can run the desert with the gloves on and get paid to heal.

Answer (score 1):

For those who can't kill the Developer yet, I found a unique way/EXPLOIT to farm for candies, which is the THIRD BEST way to farm for candies. (Killing the Nougat Monster is the 2nd Best, but requires skill/activity. Killing the developer is the 1st Best, all around.)

Regardless of Best Methods: what I'm about to explain is actually good for anyone to do---to get PASSIVE candies---I.e. you don't need to play the game for this to work. I'm sure some people might have figured something like this out before, because it's primarily a trick regarding the Introspection Boots. But hopefully I can explain it in a way so that you can get the most bang for your buck.

Get the Merchant Hat, Scythe (Double Power upgrade helps, too), Introspective Boots, Pogo Stick/BirdFeather. Go to Castle Gate. "Jump" your way to near the very end. The very very end, as far as you can go. The enemies will respawn super fast, AND THEY WON'T EVEN HIT YOU. So you don't even need the unicorn horn or the pink gloves. This is THE best way to get Candies, while NOT playing the game. Make sure to open the game in a separate browser window while doing so; otherwise, browsing in other tabs will not work.

Randomly shooting fireballs will not hit the enemies. Only the Scythe will do a lot of damage. However, one time I even got the randomly shooting fireballs to minutely assist the speed at which the enemies are killed. It's probably more work than is worth it. But it involved teleporting luckily at the exact right spot, which landed me on one of the enemies' horse's head. This suspended me in the air, probably because of weird workings of how the game operates. (This somehow allows for randomly cast fireballs to hit them.)